# Tomcat as an Enterpise server

Tags: java, tomcat, ear

It seems that tomcat is a web application server and EAR cannot be deployed in it. Can it be updated to deploy EAR files. If not what could be the alternate server which is easy to configure and deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best alternative is Glassfish Application Server, alongwith Netbeans which will be best for practice purpose. Although there are a long list of such server and also that Apache also have one such server.
....

Answer (score 4):

In Short - NO. Tomcat is not a Java EE compliant server, but just a web server.

Use JBoss/GlassFish/Geronimo, there are a lot more, just google for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Glassfish, but JBoss uses an embedded Tomcat so you might get comfortable with it somewhat easier.